# Twitter API version 2 not working with OAuth 1

Tags: python, api, twitter, version, unauthorized

I used to get Tweet data using API version 1.1 like below:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

oauth = OAuth1(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, token_secret)
requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=<TWEET_ID>', auth=oauth)
```

It's working properly, and there is no issue at all.
Now I tried to do the same thing with Twitter API version 2, but it returns 401/unauthorized

The endpoint is
`requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/<TWEET_ID>', auth=oauth)`

Could someone already try Twitter version 2 successfully? Could you tell me what I need to change? From Twitter documentation, I could use the same OAuth 1.0 for API version 2.

Comment: API v2 should indeed work fine with OAuth 1.0A authentication, although I’ve not tried the OAuth1 module from requests_oauthlib. I’ve called the API using twurl and user authentication (aka OAuth 1.0A) and this works. This call should also work with a Bearer Token.

Comment: Comparing your code to [this example](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Tweet-Lookup/get_tweets_with_user_context.py) it is not clear whether you have performed the authentication correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason, my app is standalone app, so I could not use Twitter api version 2

[image]